# How can I check the security of my website?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, http

How can I check the security of my website?

What are the best ways to avoid security holes?

Comment: Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72166/penetration-testing-tools). And all the related questions in the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript / SQL injections would be the first thing I'd safeguard against.  Also keep in mind that there are possible holes if you let users upload files to the site.  Also be wary of admin control panels (CPanel, etc) as they could be targeted to acts of brute forcing.

Answer (score 2):

If you use any 3rd party libraries, make sure to be a subscriber to their news listings, and try be informed of their security notices.

I saw an entire server taken out by a vulnerability in a 3rd party PHP library once which really was not pleasant. This may seem obvious, but you'd be surprised the majority of people don't do this, which is why the invasions are so effective. :)

Answer (score 1):

- http://php-ids.org/
- http://pixybox.seclab.tuwien.ac.at/pixy/othertools.php
- Lots of reading on security papers

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the skill/resources to do your own security testing, I would recommend [WebInspect](https://h10078.www1.hp.com/cda/hpms/display/main/hpms_content.jsp?zn=bto&cp=1-11-201-200%5E9570_4000_100__). I am not sure of the price, but this is the best tool I have tested for web security testing. A lot of tools such as Nessus won't really help in your case, because they are looking mainly at known flows in the web server or in known packages.

Comment: There are companies that offer this sort of testing on a regular basis as a service as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Ratproxy](http://code.google.com/p/ratproxy/) :

> A semi-automated, largely passive web
>   application security audit tool,
>   optimized for an accurate and
>   sensitive detection, and automatic
>   annotation, of potential problems and
>   security-relevant design patterns
>   based on the observation of existing,
>   user-initiated traffic in complex web
>   2.0 environments.
>
> Detects and prioritizes broad classes
>   of security problems, such as dynamic
>   cross-site trust model considerations,
>   script inclusion issues, content
>   serving problems, insufficient XSRF
>   and XSS defenses, and much more.

You use ratproxy while you use application as normal and it highlights potential security flaws.

Answer (score 0):

I will start from the second question. To void security holes on your website you have to follow several steps:

1. If you use open-source CMS (like Joomla, Drupal or others) keep it up to date. Also update 3rd party components, modules, etc. on a regular basis (as soon as possible). This is probably the most important step.
2. Install secure FTP client (like WinSCP) and use most secure connection
3. Change all your FTP passwords. Use strong passwords.
4. Change logins the administrative backend at your site
5. Check .htaccess file permisions and contents. Get this file if you haven’t used it before.
6. Ensure you don’t have any forgotten php file browsers in your web folder.

Now, if you want to test website security there are number of free and open source tools. I’d recommend starting with [w3af](http://w3af.sourceforge.net/) – it’s a comprehensive website audit framework. However, you will have to play with it a little bit. A lot simpler is websecurify. If you just want to have quick results use websecurify. I found a blog post describing the most popular free website security testing tools.

However, if you’re a complete novice, I would recommend ordering a website security test from a professional. Check for example [webyfly.com](http://www.webyfly.com).

Comment: You are not really clear about AVOIDING FTP at all costs, and use an encrypted method like SCP instead. You are also only targeting passwords and very specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

1. In response to [Robert Mirek answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10980696/447356) - I would not recommend CMS updates as a default. Updating is not always effective as new versions tend to come with new, yet to be patched, exploits. The main problem here is not the even version itself but all the plug-ins (or extensions or modules) that need to be updated and with every such update the chance for vulnerability grows. Wait a few days and read a round before updating, you`ll save yourself a lot of problems.
2. Regarding site security check. The question should be more specific. What are you worried about (SQL injection, Illegal access, XSS, scraping? ) Some attacks can not be avoided (i.e. botnet DDoS) and must be absorbed via 3rd-party solutions, others can be mitigated with WAF.

I work for a security company (Incapsula) and after seeing and reading alot about the subject I can tell you one thing - checking is almost irrelevant, if you are not behind a strong WAF and Cloud based DDoS mitigation platform, you are not secured.