# Advice on code scanning / penetration testing tools

Tags: security, xss, sql-injection, penetration-testing

As far as I can see the offerings fall into two categories – scanning services such as McAfee, Comodo, etc. and tools such as Burp Proxy, HP’s WebInspect,CodeScan, etc.

In an ideal world, I’d use something that actively scanned a certain URL (the target being a LAMP stack) on a daily basis (or as required if it’s a standalone tool), but I’m a bit wary of standalone tools in terms of their coverage and frequency of updating. (The ‘remote’ scanners such as McAfee are presumably updated as required.)

I’ve also had issues with some standalone tools (can’t remember which one unfortunately) that managed to get themselves lost within our URL rewriting system (there’s a facetted search in play, so you can imagine things get fairly deep on the URL front).

As such, I’m just wondering what experiences people have had with the offerings out there and whether the standalone tools stack up against the scanning services.

(Incidentally, I'm aware of [Penetration testing tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72166/penetration-testing-tools) - I'm just wondering if the situation has changed since then)

Comment: It would be tough to improve on the accepted answer given in the original question.

Comment: Cool - if that's still the state of play, I'll close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done penetration testing and [exploit development](http://milw0rm.com/author/677).  I can tell you from first hand experience that hacking isn't just firing off some tool.  Sometimes tools can make life easier,  but if you don't know what you are doing then a tool isn't going to help.

If you want to **KNOW** that your system is secure then you need to higher a skilled hacker to break in.   The PCI-DSS is a certification required for credit card processing which mandates that you have regular penetration testing conducted on your server.   Conducting regular penetration testing  is something that you should adopt if you want to have a very secure server.

A very good security measure for web servers is a Web Application Firewall (WAF).  WAFs are also required by the PCI-DSS. [Mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org/) is free and open source WAF.  Mod_Security can be used to prevent hundreds of different types of attacks.  A WAF can be a nightmare for a penetration tester or would be hacker.