# What are you sneakiest code injection attacks to PHP?

Tags: php, security

I am writing an automatic tester for our web application's API. Im trying to break it and expose flaws. So far I am trying:

1. missing parameters
2. additional "guess" parameters (ex: `admin=1`)
3. malicious parameters: sending something like  `eval("echo 'injection';");` all encoded in `%` encoding
4. other classic SQL injection attacks like `OR 1=1`, comments `--`

I'm not really trying to go for stuff like drop tables, I dont want to damage our test environment. All of my attacks are more aimed at printing messages so I know I got around our security without deleting information.

Comment: Do not over estimate the ability of scanners to discover flaws, they usually return only the most obvious ones, anyone with little experience in website security would've found anyway. There unfortuntely is tons of vendors and ways to exploit a web application, xss, csrf and sql injection to name the few popular ones, and there is more every day. So remember that white lists are better then black lists, that no data supplied by user should be trusted and try to reflect that in the code.

Comment: if you aren't experienced in that - why do you going to write it? A few short answers will not substitute required knowledge. Most likely you just wannabe a script-kiddie and exploit some site with minimum efforts. Especially with such a username.

Answer (score 2):

There are a wide variety of automated testers already out there and it probably makes more sense to take advantage of these, as you'll inevitably overlook some aspect of your own code, etc.

In terms of the penetration testing tools, the [Penetration testing tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72166/penetration-testing-tools) question has a through discussion including software recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend that you don't do this yourself.  There are tons of different attack vectors and this could be a full time job for quite a long time.  It's not something you bang out over a week or two.

Instead go look at [Metasploit](http://www.metasploit.com/).  It's an awesome pen testing framework.  I guarantee anyone that knows what they are doing when trying to hack a site has this.  You may as well use the same tools.

Comment: From my understanding asda* wants to pentest a web application, metasploit is used mainly to attack server vulnerabilities... Check out Nikto if anything, which still won't find web application flaws though

Answer (score 0):

The open source vulnerablity scanner [W3AF](http://w3af.sourceforge.net/plugin-descriptions.php) can scan for the following vulnerabilities that affect PHP applications:

```
LFI/RFI
LDAPi
SQLi
XSS
OS Command Execution
CRLF injection
Directory Traversal
```

And many more.